# Weight saving between Sora and 105

Tags: shimano

I would like to know what is the weight difference between Sora and 105 group set.

Comment: Go to Shimano's site, pick the parts you want on 105, corresponding parts on Sora and then sum up the weights for each groupset and take the difference. This answer depends at least on if you're running a Sora triple and 105 triple vs the doubles vs compact doubles (if they're in both groupsets).

Comment: Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: @Batman, I can't easily find that information on Shimano's (new and shiny) website. For example, [this](http://cycle.shimano-eu.com/content/seh-bike/en/home/mtb/drivetrain/crankset/fc-m675.html) is my crank. How much does it weight?

Comment: I am adding as a comment since links change, try Weight Weenies.com  web site. There is almost everything to do with component weight and not much else.

Comment: If you ask for weight comparison, at least specify what groups models you want to compare.

Comment: Let me explain.. I have a new 105  5700 groupset. I want to buy a 2015 Lapierre Audacio 300 which is fitted with sora tripple components. I have tried to find the weight of the Sora tripple group set but were unable to. I know the weight of my 105  5700 groupset and am trying to determine my weight deduction as the Lapierre is rather on the hefty side. 9.4 kg, so i'm trying to determine if I will get bthe weight close to 8kg by fitting my 105 groupset and Fulcrum 3 wheels

Comment: If you want the weight of Sora Tripple then why did you not just ask that?

Comment: Blam I suppose you have the answer...

Comment: Batman, thanks for the suggestion. I have tried just about every site and taken all advice but cant find the weight for Sora components. I have just downloaded all the groupsets from Shimano's website and the component weight stops at Tiagra. I'll bite the bullet and hope i save enough weight by replacing the wheels and then fitting the 105  5700 compact groupset on the Lapierre. If I can manage to save 1000 grams it will bring the weight down to 8.4kg which is ok. Thanks for the help and suggestions

Answer (score 3):

Since nobody so far has posted weights, I'll leave "one" data in case it's useful for somebody.

```
                   | 105 5800 | Sora 3500 |
-------------------+----------+-----------+
Levers             |     486g |      496g |
Brakes             |     388g |      357g |
Front Derailleur   |      89g |      105g |
Rear Derailleur    |     234g |      246g |
Crankset           |          |      844g |
Crankset (with BB) |     808g |           |
Cassettes          |     269g |      343g |
Chain              |     257g |      270g |
-------------------+----------+-----------+
Total              |    2531g |     2661g |
```

- 105 is average weights with BB, and Sora is one actual weights **without** BB.
- The sources of 105 are [multiple](http://cyclepine.com/blog/store_information/5915.html) [shops](http://www.cb-asahi.co.jp/html/road_upgrade.html) (Not in English). I think they just list what Shimano claims but doesn't make it available online for whatever reasons.
- The source on Sora is [this blog](http://retao.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/04/28/231436) (not in English too, but with photos of each part on a platform scale).
- Actual weights will vary depending on the crank length, the gear size, the cassette combination, the derailleur capacity, or even quality of individual parts (yours may be slightly lighter or heavier than average).

Comment: Quote your source?

Comment: @Vorac Unfortunately, I don't have any source in English, but I just elaborated my post and added where info came from.

Comment: Deburim,thanks for the info. I cant believe the weight gain is sooooo little. Damn, will have to rethink and maybe go with SRAM Rival to shed more weight.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond a weight - you also need to look at Number of gears, Under tape cable routing, Stiffer cranks, Dual Pivot SLR braking, Aesthetics, Performance (slicker shifting for starters).

Comment: I would guess the OP would be happy with comparable components from both lines e.g. same number of gears, same cable routing etc.

Comment: I have a complete 105 5700 groupset so will upgrade to 10 speed and a set of Fulcrum 3 wheels.

Comment: As of 2020 (even earlier actually) Sora these days can do the internal cable and, the cranks are quite similar, just perhaps not hollow and hence heavier, if they use the main line cranks with Hollowtech II and not the cheeaper Octalink ones. A new difference these days will be hydraulic disc brakes vs mechanical disc brakes. Better shifting - probably yes, but lower speed chainsets appear more robust to me.